# Regular expression for JSON code

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm trying to extract the access_token value.
anyone know how to extract this.

```
{"access_token":"c170f85d-9371-31c3-a4fa-1f0865ef28da","refresh_token":"6312ab1a-e257-38e9-aab1-8f8071dfd643","scope":"openid","id_token":"eyJ4NXQiOiJOVEF4Wm1NeE5ETXlaRGczTVRVMVpHTTBNekV6T0RKaFpXSTRORE5sWkRVMU9HRmtOakZpTVEiLCJraWQiOiJOVEF4Wm1NeE5ETXlaRGczTVRVMVpHTTBNekV6T0RKaFpXSTRORE5sWkRVMU9HRmtOakZpTVEiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdF9oYXNoIjoibTFGZUk4ZFJFbDV6azZoTFd2VUxBUSIsImNfaGFzaCI6IkRGbVY3RUt4dzlhck4xNFhDOUxQT1EiLCJzdWIiOiJzb2wxdXNlcjYwIiwiYXVkIjpbInRlc3RtYW5lZXNoYWNvZGUwMDAwMDAxMjMwMDAwIl0sImF6cCI6InRlc3RtYW5lZXNoYWNvZGUwMDAwMDAxMjMwMDAwIiwiYW1yIjpbIkJhc2ljQXV0aGVudGljYXRvciJdLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvbG9jYWxob3N0Ojk0NDNcL29hdXRoMlwvdG9rZW4iLCJleHAiOjE1MzM3Mjk4MjYsImlhdCI6MTUzMzcyNjIyNiwic2lkIjoiZmE0NDNjZTMtNTI0MS00N2ZkLWIxYzYtMDkxNTU1ODNmZDcwIn0.J6ymae3s4UOvNRiJIL_kdni4HRgUoIHf4speGduQjGd_ny_3ow0MjxHW51wxJfAWpSw9a8cMfc5DkI0lgQmPoWUeNlQ1-loNOGPCMREE4PfJPG312psjxecIjU0j7fr8ma-wAkPKMicSK1VrrbURgU9XdVjve3iVOyAW7ypuGuIgOqwulQdYMldTVBrixWjQvjmygezV30V48OAY8oNIrp6nLWzBUV9w9Zb7_ASblLSezMceIecHMl-0EBAnMYvqgxtbk8aB* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact tLOsz3bqAonEMk3EvnWrQ7GsL2Mrtc_Wo2n7bfv3fkdjkeeb8fuVqUuC4nG-u2In9hdck8HOXoojZQ","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":2881}
```

I need to get `c170f85d-9371-31c3-a4fa-1f0865ef28da` only from above response.

How can I get it using a regex?

Comment: Regex for jason: `^.*jason.*$` :-) ... jokes aside, please _don't_ use pure regex to try to extract things from JSON content.  You should use some sort of JSON (not Jason) parser.

Comment: yes, as already suggested a Json parser would work best for this

Answer (score 0):

Add a [JSON extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child to the request where you are getting above response

use `$..access_token` as JSON path expression.
 Match no `1`
give name to variable

TO access the variable you can use `${variablename}`

For more info on regular expression extraction [follow this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)